# Use ratings and reviews with custom eav entity

Tags: review, ratings, entities

I'm looking for a way of being able to use Reviews and Ratings with a custom eav entity. Without creating a custom table. Any ideas to put point me in the write direction ?

Comment: I cannot understand what you are asking

Comment: basically i was asking for a way to use reviews to allow for a custom eac entity type, i created an eav structure, lets say product documentation, and want to be able to let that eav attribute be reciewed using the entity_type_id.